# Python Selenium: Finding and filling out the dropbox and textbox fields from a given website

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu, textbox, dropdown

I am trying to build a function to run the information on the following website using Selenium in Python: https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address. The function should do the following, given the single line address variable named address_to_search in the arguments:

1. Load the webpage url with Selenium
2. Change the lookup dropdown in Step 2 to “freeform address”
3. Insert address_to_search into the textbox in Step 3
4. Return the resulting address information (for now as a text file is fine)

Here’s the incomplete function code:

```
def get_property_info(address_to_search):
    url = 'https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver')
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source
```

Whenever I load the url, though, I do not see a dropbox for Step 2 in the driver’s page source to be able to change it or the address fields in Step 3 to insert the given search into. If changing the dropdown in 2 above is not possible, I can change the input to load each address item (address line 1, address line 2, city, state, zip code separately) even though that approach is less ideal, but either way I can’t access the items in Step 3 anyways.

Do you have any suggestions for how to locate these items on the webpage and otherwise build the functions?

Comment: You can't access them because those elements are in an iframe. Instead navigate to https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address-iframe and do the search. I dont understand under 4th point why do you want the function to return a text file?

Answer (score 0):

As I've mentioned in my comment you are stuck because it's a seperate iframe.
Just navigate to that iframe and do the magic.
If your address will have "\n" at the end like mine does you'll see the result display (the newline char acts as enter key).
I've also added driver argument, since I declared it outside. You can just modify that to your need.

```
address = "3301 South Greenfield Rd Gilbert, AZ 85297\n"

def get_property_info(driver,address_to_search):
    url = 'https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address-iframe'
    driver.get(url)
    driver.find_element_by_id("lookup-select-button").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("lookup-select").find_element_by_id("address-freeform").click()
    driver.find_element_by_id("freeform-address").send_keys(address_to_search)

   #return driver.page_source

get_property_info(driver,address)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is one iframe as mentioned, also I think you should use maximize your windows through selenium, should use explicit waits as well :-

Below is the code that does the magic :-

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(50)
driver.get("https://www.smartystreets.com/products/single-address")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[title='iframe']")))
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 500)")
ele = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "lookup-select")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", ele)
ele.click()
time.sleep(5)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "address-freeform"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "freeform-address"))).send_keys("3503 Adonais Way, Norcross")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "submit-request"))).click()
```

**Imports :**

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```